# Edit couldn't be submitted -- how to finish review? Load title and tag edits asynchronously

Tags: discussion, feature-request, bug, editing, review

I was reviewing a possible "Low Quality Post" and decided to edit it.

I completely revised title, body and tags to contain proper English, describe the post and improve the MathJax.

Then, I tried to submit. I got this:

[image: How to finish review]

How can I ever finish my review now? (I eventually copied title and body, cancelled the edit, voted "looks good" and manually applied the edit. But that's ridiculous.)

This type of annoyance is quite common when doing a substantial revision in the review queue. This particular instance is worse than most, because *only the tags were altered*.

My suggested solution (to be applied to editing in any circumstance):

> Have a link/button available to load the tag edit asynchronously -- similarly for title edits.

That is, let me stay in the current window, and when I click "load edit", replace the title/tags with the edited version. Being synced with the other edit,  I can now decide to alter that part of the post as well, just as if I had started editing *after* the concurrent edit -- but without losing my precious edit of the question body.

---

Please feel free to suggest other solutions in the answers.

---

**Edit:** Added [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) in view of [this MSO thread](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/93169/222340).

Comment: Sigh... the problem of race conditions. It is a good thing that they are preventing us from overwriting each other's edits; it is bad that the lock is only activated post editing, and not pre.

Comment: @WillieWong It's good that they prevent *unconscious* overwriting. The obvious problem with pre-submission locking is windows being left open by the first editor. Determining a time limit on the lock will recreate the problem, albeit in smaller volume.

Comment: Related question: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/8917/editing-long-questions-in-stages